# Any number multiplies by zero equals to zero but why the factorial number of zero equals 1?

Tags: language-agnostic

Mathematically speaking, zero is the absobing element of the multiplication. I would like to know why the factorial number of zero equals 1? Is this general accepted rule?

Can someone reason about this factorial concept based on this factorial formula?

```
         n!=n×(n−1)×(n−2)×………×1 

         0! = 0 * 0 = 1
         1! = 1 * 1 = 1
         2! = 2 * 1 = 2
         3! = 3 * 2 * 1 = 6
         4! = 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 24
         5! = 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 120
         6! = 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 720
```

Comment: Should your example not use `0! = 0 = 1` and `1! = 1 = 1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a description](https://www.vedantu.com/question-answer/explain-zero-factorial-class-11-maths-cbse-6040d4d2bb704a431efe9b61) with multiple definitions. 0! is always 1, in mathematics as well as programming. It has to do with data sets.